# chrome.debugger.attach to popup with Debuggee type

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting my feet wet with Chrome extension development, and I'm trying to adapt the code from the [HTTP live headers extension sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:debugger) to display the headers within the popup window as opposed to in a separate debug window.

I'm in fact having no success at all attaching the debugger to anything other than the separate window as was included with the sample code.

I've tried two approaches with the code in popup.js, firstly to add `chrome.debugger.attach(@@extension_id, "0.1")` which gives an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

Secondly, this in popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query(
    {currentWindow:true},
    function(tabs) {
        var tabId = tabs[0]
        chrome.debugger.attach(
            tabId,
            "1.0",
            function() { console.log("hello?") }
        )
    }
)
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Error in response to tabs.query: Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'active': Unexpected property, Property 'audible': Unexpected property, Property 'autoDiscardable': Unexpected property, Property 'discarded': Unexpected property, Property 'height': Unexpected property, Property 'highlighted': Unexpected property, Property 'id': Unexpected property, Property 'incognito': Unexpected property, Property 'index': Unexpected property, Property 'mutedInfo': Unexpected property, Property 'pinned': Unexpected property, Property 'selected': Unexpected property, Property 'status': Unexpected property, Property 'width': Unexpected property, Property 'windowId': Unexpected property.
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://kmappdoedakemifdcbjiojlffegjbkcf/popup.js:16:25)
    at chrome-extension://kmappdoedakemifdcbjiojlffegjbkcf/popup.js:12:13
```

These errors were seen by inspecting the popup (by right-clicking the extension browser action button and selecting 'Inspect') and then checking the console. I have minimal experience with JavaScript so forgive me if this is all very stupid.

Comment: Note that 1. the popup is not a tab so it doesn't have a tabId, 2. the popup window exists only when it's actually shown.

Comment: @wOxxOm The popup is still shown after inspecting it, so that's okay I think. How does @@extension_id relate to the popup, and what's up with the error with that approach? And more generally, what's the right way to kind of "hook in" to the popup? Well, to attach this debugger to it, specifically. Is it even possible?

Comment: I haven't used chrome.debugger so wait for someone else to answer authoritatively. What I know is that 1) Chrome doesn't support multiple debuggers attached to one target so if you inspect the popup in devtools, it's a no go, you need to open the popup normally 2) run `chrome.debugger.getTargets(console.log)` to see available targets. 3) you can open the popup page as a normal tab by pasting its full URL in the addressbar.

Answer (score 1):

The callback for tabs gives you a tab instead of the tab ID. In that case, you should change,

```
var tabId = tabs[0];
```

to

```
var tabId = tabs[0].id;
```